# Unable to resolve target 'android-11' in eclipse though android-11 is installed in pc

Tags: android

I have installed Android 3.0(API 11)- SDK platform and google APIs in my pc.

When I open an existing android project in eclipse which targets to Android-11, I get 
Unable to resolve target 'android-11' error

I have tried adding the android-sdk tools folder path in system path environment variable.

The issue exists still
I guess eclipse is unable to pick up the installed android adk path. Or is it due to any other issue?

Comment: Eclipse restarted? Go to settings and check the sdk path.

Comment: What about the ADT plugin? Is it updated to support api level 11?

Comment: I changed the sdk path in preferences and it worked.thanks

Answer (score 5):

Go to the file project.properties and change target from android 11(3.0 HC) to 15(4.0.3 ICS) or any other available android SDK platform version with you. See below.

```
# Project target.
target=android-11 to target=android-15.
```

This happens when you are updating android thru the SDK Manager and you delete packages which your previously created projects are using.

Comment: But it says right in project.properties "# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!"

Answer (score 1):

Try to add min sdk and target sdk version in manifest file

```
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this helps:

Context-Menu of the project >> Android Tools >> Fix Project Properties.